# Write File to external SdCard at arbitary locations

Tags: android, android-permissions, file-permissions, android-sdcard, android-fileprovider

I'm getting a bit mad about all the confusion about `externalStorage` `/sdcard` mount point and the different permissions I need. I'm only referring to an **external physical sdCard**, mounted in `/storage/XXXX-XXXX/` not the "externalStorage" usually mounted in `/sdcard/`.

I already read lots of topics including [this](https://possiblemobile.com/2014/03/android-external-storage/) comprehensive guide  (although it may be a bit outdated). 
It clearly states that:

> The secondary volume(s) modify write permissions a bit; they are
>   globally readable under the same permission described above. 
>   Directories outside the application’s own managed area (i.e.
>   /Android/data/[PACKAGE_NAME]) are not writable at all by that
>   application.

I'm well aware on how to write to my Apps "private" directory at ie.
`/storage/5060-5A88/Android/data/my.apps.namespace/`.

What I read Is that it is **not** possible to write a new file to lets say:
`/storage/5060-5A88/Pics4All`.

However I downloaded 2 "File Explorer Apps" (Google Files, CxFileExplorer) and checked my external SdCard from there. As soon as I wanted to Write something (like a folder or copy a File) these Apps ask me to approve:

Grant **AppName** access to your data, including photos and videos, on **sdCard Name**.

After granting, I'm able to create folders, move files, etc... without the need on user-interaction on file-choosers or their likes. Also there is a special Tab in the Settings->App->Storage saying

"External Storage" 1 item
and a "Clear access" button below it.

So my question is: How did these Explorer Apps get the permissions to write at arbitary locations on my sdCard? Which API do they use I might have missed?

Comment: They are using the Storage Access Framework. Given that description, they are probably using `StorageManager` and `StorageVolume`, though those APIs are deprecated on Android Q. In general, use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Doesn't `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` involve a user interaction, given that you call `startActivityForResult` ? If so, must the user grant this at every app start or is it sufficient for him to do it once?

Comment: "Doesn't ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE involve a user interaction, given that you call startActivityForResult ?" -- yes. "If so, must the user grant this at every app start or is it sufficient for him to do it once?" -- you can call `takePersistableUriPermission()` for the `Uri` that you get back from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. That should give you durable access, within practical limits (e.g., user deletes the tree using some other tool).